# What kind of Service should I use for a background downloader

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I'd like a background thread to download images from the internet and store them in a queue. When the queue reaches a certain size, I'd like the thread to sleep/stop.

I'd want this queue to be accessable across all activities. When I poll from the queue, it would wake up the thread to start downloading again until full, etc.

I've read here and on the Android site that a Service is probably what I'm looking for, and it would create the thread that runs in the background. This would be accessable across activities.

To access the queue, I should use a Bound Service? I don't want the service to be alive all the time, just accessable when I want images and to only download when the queue isn't full. From what I understand, the service is destroyed if everyone unbinds from it, unless I call startservice, but then I'd have to stop it manually?

What should I do? When the service is destroyed, I figure the queue would be as well...

Comment: so you want to provide some external content (images) to your app, so whats wrong with a custom `ContentProvider`?

Comment: From the Android site: A content provider is only required if you need to share data between multiple applications. I don't have such a need...

Comment: the docs are out of date, your app also needs it for other things like search suggestions, `CursorLoader` and couple of other things

Comment: It doesn't look at all related to what I'm trying to do. Contentproviders give an interface to a repository of data...it's an alternative to using a SQL database and preferred when the data is shared between apps. I don't have a repository, I want to download files in the background as needed.

Comment: I don't want to download the file when I need it, I want a bunch of files downloaded in the background, available when I need them, from any activity. I definitely don't want to store them in the filesystem. All this is moot however since I'm not downloading from any Uri

Comment: As I have said, contentprovider will not prove to be a solution to my app. Services are what I need, and it's unclear to me how to implement one for my goal.

Comment: Yes you need to stop the service manually.and you can use Bond Services.Check this link to implement bound services.https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html

Comment: I read that already I need more details for what I'm trying to develop, hence posting here.

Comment: `"and it's unclear to me how to implement one for my goal."` see how [DocumentsProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/DocumentsProvider.html) delivers data, from the docs `"Base class for a document provider. A document provider offers read and write access to durable files, such as files stored on a local disk, or files in a cloud storage service."`, see in the sources where abstract `openDocument` method is called

Comment: I've already told you that a service provider won't be useful for my problem. Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: how is your case different from a `DocumentsProvider` that *"offers read access to files [...] in a cloud storage service."* ? note that you dont have to make a handshake like in regular bound services (using a `Binder`), define your own interface for receiving your files to the clients, worry about service's life-cycle etc, instead you have already defined API for getting your data, all you need to do is to feed it with the bytes

Comment: There are no files to read, I'm generating screenshots of webpages on the fly. And as I've said multiple times, I want it downloaded ahead of time, not as I need it.

Comment: you are right, use services, this is what you need